# Text-overflow ellipsis doesn't seem to work even when I provide h4 tag with width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
    

* {

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }
.latestmanga {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;

}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  
}
li {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.textContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 0.4rem;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.textContent span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h4 {
  color: #059e9a;
}

.textContent a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  width: 100%;
}

li a:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f101";
  font-weight: 900;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.4rem;
}
li a:after {
  content: attr(time);
  float: right;
  color: #aeae9f;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
    

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"

      />

      <title>Page title</title>

    </head>

    <body>
<section class="latestmanga"> 
    <ul>
               <li>
   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/23/q/23-1612849460.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="textContent">
   <h4>It feels so wrong to bite people</h4>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 93</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 92</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="1 day ago">CHAPTER 91</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/5/d/23-1610420366.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textContent">
   <h4>Rebirth Of The Earth Immortal Venerable</h4>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="3 hours ago">CHAPTER 164</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="7 days ago">CHAPTER 163</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="15 days ago">CHAPTER 162</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   </div>
 </li>
           </ul>
</section>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I want h4 tag text to ellipsis on smaller devices which currently isn't working even if I provide h4 with some width I don't know what I am doing wrong and would be good if someone could address what the problem is. Thanks in advance. I want the h4 tag text content to be like "Rebirth Of The Earth Immortal...... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the parent element have set `display: flex`, You can  just add a wrapper to `h4` and set a `min-width` to the warpper like below:

```css
    

* {

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }
.latestmanga {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;

}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  
}
li {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.textContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 0.4rem;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.textContent span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper {
  min-width: 200px;
}

h4 {
  color: #059e9a;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.textContent a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  width: 100%;
}

li a:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f101";
  font-weight: 900;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.4rem;
}
li a:after {
  content: attr(time);
  float: right;
  color: #aeae9f;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
    

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"

      />

      <title>Page title</title>

    </head>

    <body>
<section class="latestmanga"> 
    <ul>
               <li>
   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/23/q/23-1612849460.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="textContent">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <h4>It feels so wrong to bite people</h4>
   </div>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 93</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 92</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="1 day ago">CHAPTER 91</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/5/d/23-1610420366.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textContent">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <h4>Rebirth Of The Earth Immortal Venerable</h4>
   </div>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="3 hours ago">CHAPTER 164</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="7 days ago">CHAPTER 163</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   <span>
     <a href="" time="15 days ago">CHAPTER 162</a>
     <p></p>
   </span>
   </div>
 </li>
           </ul>
</section>
    </body>

    </html>
```